# emacs: limit number of colors used by font-lock

Tags: emacs, xterm

I have my terminal configured to use the solarized color palette. I would like to simply limit emacs to 8 colors so that `font-lock` uses the same colors as my terminal. I can accomplish this by running emacs with `TERM=xterm-color` but this is causing some other terminal issues.

Is there another way to limit the number of colors available? As far as I can tell emacs configures this directly from the terminal parameters.

Comment: setting `TERM=xterm` should use 8 colors, because that's standard.  If it doesn't, there's some misconfiguration on your computer.